# How do I throw an error handler if parameter doesn't exist in table?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, error-handling

So I have this stored procedure:

```
delimiter //
create procedure sp_finish_campaign(in c_title varchar(30))
begin 
    update campaign set CAMPAIGNFINISHDATE = CURDATE()
    where TITLE = c_title;
end//
delimiter ;
```

I want to know how to throw an error handler with a message if the c_title parameter doesn't exist in the campaign table. I have tried using

`DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42000'
 SELECT 'Error!';`

and some if statements but either the syntax is wrong or it comes up with an error 1054 unknown column title in fieldlist.

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
create procedure sp_finish_campaign(in c_title varchar(30))
begin 
    update campaign set CAMPAIGNFINISHDATE = CURDATE()
    where TITLE = c_title;

    if @@rowcount=0
    begin
      DECLARE @ErrorMessage  NVARCHAR(4000);
      DECLARE @V_ErrorCode   INT;
      DECLARE @ErrorState    INT;

      SELECT @V_ErrorCode   = 50000 ,
             @ErrorMessage  = c_title+ ' is not exists' ,
             @ErrorState    = 1
      THROW @V_ErrorCode,@ErrorMessage,@ErrorState

    end
end//
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all, getting syntax errors all around